# "She sings as beautiful as a nightingale" or "She sings as beautifully as a nightingale"?

Tags: grammar

The title says it all, which one is correct?

> She sings as beautiful as a nightingale.

OR:

> She sings as beautifully as a nightingale?

I am not a native speaker myself, but for me "She sings as beautiful as a nightingale", sounds more correct to me.

But grammatically, It doesn't seem right, it's supposed to be "beautifully", because it has the verb "sing" before it.

So, Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 3):

### Beautifully.

---

"Beautiful" is an adjective, while "beautifully" is an adverb. Here you want an adverb, because it applies to the verb, "sings".

Comment: I know... but... it doesn't sound right, maybe it's just me.

Comment: Hello, seaturtle. I find it disturbing that (1) this question should be asked on a site aimed at linguists, (2) this question should be answered rather than close-voted on a site aimed at linguists; (3) the answer should be upvoted.